# LibGDX - 1-Byte Array Size Varies On Different Resolution

Tags: android, libgdx, textures

I'm currently developing a game using libGDX; however, when running it on my two different devices, there is a huge difference in memory usage.

I'm currently using a HTC One X+, and a Nexus 7 for testing. While testing, I've noticed that the Nexus 7 has a larger heap size and is also using more of that heap. While looking into it with the Android Device Monitor, I have noticed that the 1-Byte Array is completely different between devices( 6 MB vs 48 KB ) while everything else is fairly similar.

I believe the issue is with textures and the different resolutions between the devices ( 1280x720 vs 1920×1200 ) and how libGDX stores the information. Although, unlike normal Android programming, there is no way to have different sets of textures ( drawable-hdpi vs drawable-xxhdpi ), as all of them go within the assets folder.

How can I improve on the memory that this is currently using?

Below is some of the data I've been looking into. This is just sitting at the main menu with 2 textures being displayed, and nothing being updated.

### HTC One X+ Heap - **62.70% Used** ( 1280 x 720 )

[image: HTC One X+ Heap]

### Nexus 7 Heap - **94.53% Used** ( 1920 x 1200 )

[image: Nexus 7 Heap]

### Data Compared

```
    Nexus 7 (vs)    HTC One X+
```

Heap    :   9.6 MB  (vs)    4.8 MB
Allocated   :   9.1 MB  (vs)    3.0 MB
Free    :   537 KB  (vs)    1.8 MB
Used    :   94.53%  (vs)    62.70%
Objects :   48,024  (vs)    46,012

free    :   402 KB  (vs)    1.8 MB

data    :   914 KB  (vs)    860 KB
class   :   1 MB    (vs)    1.1 MB
**1-byte    :   6 MB    (vs)    48.6 KB**
2-byte  :   705 KB  (vs)    633 KB
4-byte  :   399 KB  (vs)    405 KB
8-byte  :   9.3 KB  (vs)    6 KB
non-Java    :   70 KB   (vs)    6 KB

### Logcat (Garbage collector being called fairly often.)

07-19 05:39:09.651    6453-6469/com.mygdx.game.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 524K, 7% free 9442K/10128K, paused 19ms, total 20ms
07-19 05:39:12.644    6453-6469/com.mygdx.game.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 512K, 7% free 9442K/10128K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
07-19 05:39:15.657    6453-6469/com.mygdx.game.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 512K, 7% free 9442K/10128K, paused 24ms, total 25ms
07-19 05:39:18.660    6453-6469/com.mygdx.game.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 511K, 7% free 9442K/10128K, paused 24ms, total 24ms

### Edit:

I created a new project using the [LibGDX Setup App](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html) within Android Studio (Beta) 0.8.0.
The only changes to code was to build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
```

instead of

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10+'
```

It still is currently using 96% of my heap space on the Nexus 7.

```
public class myGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can hint, but don't control garbage collection. What is the actual problem you're experiencing?

Comment: The problem is that on the Nexus 7, the garbage collector is being called fairly often, which is causing framerate issues. Whereas on a lower resolution device, such as the HTC One X+, I'm not having any garbage collection calls.

Comment: In that case, make sure that there's nothing for the GC to be collected. E.g. don't create objects in frequently called methods like the `render` method. Also keep in mind that something like string concatenation (e.g. `"score: "+score`) might cause the GC to kick in, use a `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: But the issue is that I'm not actually creating anything yet. The tests I did were on a main menu with only 2 textures (background, and title ). On my Nexus 7, most of the heap is already used before I even create any objects.

Comment: How do you know that the garbage collector is being called fairly often?

Comment: I noticed it while watching LogCat while testing on my Nexus 7.

`GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 524K, 7% free 9442K/10128K, paused 19ms, total 20ms`

I will often get these messages ( ranging from every few seconds to every 15 seconds ) about the garbage collector is being called, and there is only ~5-10% free.

Comment: Apparently there are objects frequently being created, otherwise there wouldn't be anything for the GC to collect. Consider showing the actual code, otherwise it will be hard to say anything more than that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57613/discussion-between-user3106174-and-xoppa).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same tools to find out *why* memory is being allocated.  You can get a backtrace to the offending code.  That should help explain where your 1-byte arrays are coming from.  (And as Xoppa says, the GC doesn't run if you're not allocating stuff, so you must be directly or indirectly triggering allocations, as a rule you don't want *any* allocations in frequently run methods like `render`).

Just use the next tab over ("Allocation Tracker").  Get your app into a steady state (allocations during startup aren't that interesting yet).  Go to the tab, click "Start Tracking", wait 5-10 seconds, click "Get Allocations", and you should see very precise answers as to who is allocating memory and why.  See http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

(The Nexus 7 has a larger heap, so it may just let more stuff accumulate on the heap before running a GC, vs. the smaller heap which needs to be collected more frequently, so less stuff gets to accumulate.)

Comment: I used the Allocation Tracker to figure out why I was having allocations within my update methods, and it was simply enchanted for loops.   
`for( Entity e : entities )`   
But the problem is that even just launching my application, I'm getting garbage collection almost immediately. For example, on my main menu, I create a Player. Nothing huge, but it's saying that already there is only 5% of the heap remaining.  

This is odd because this isn't happening on my other devices, and the massive 1-byte array is only there on the Nexus. I'm wondering if it's scaling a texture and saving it somehow.

Comment: Even after creating a completely new project, with only the default badlogic.jpg showing on the screen, it's still using 96% of my heap space. I created a discussion, [link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57613/discussion-between-user3106174-and-xoppa) to see why this would be the case.